# Android Volley - No Response from StringRequest

Tags: android, json, connection, android-volley

I'm unable to get `JSON` Response when using **Android Volley**. No Error also No Succesfull response see (`Log.d("logr=",_response);`). I use StringRequest to get JSON text from **Google Map API Android V2**. Here're the code

```
private String urla = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=";
private String urlb = "&types=hotel&radius=500&sensor=false&key=YOUR_KEY";


   @Override //::LocationListener (Interface)
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        //Log.d(TAG, "Firing onLocationChanged..............................................");
        mCurrentLocation = location;
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()), 13);
        googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

        double x = location.getLatitude();
        double y = location.getLongitude();

        String request = urla+x+","+y+urlb;
        Log.d("log1=",request);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, request,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String _response) {

                        Log.d("logr=",_response);

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                // Error handling
                Log.d("log2=", error.toString());
                Log.e("log3=", error.toString());
            }
        });


        Toast.makeText(activity, "Update location user ==>" + mCurrentLocation.getLatitude() + "," + mCurrentLocation.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "Current Location :" + mCurrentLocation.getLatitude() + "," + mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
    }
```

Any Solution to this problem ?

Comment: why using volley for this for google maps??

Comment: @VivekMishra  I'm learning volley also to avoid write too many codes...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Where do you actually excecute the request? You have to `add()` it to Volley's `RequestQueue`, otherwise the request does not get send at all.

```
// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

String url = urla + x + "," + y + urlb;

StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String _response) {

                Log.d("logr=",_response);

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        // Error handling
        Log.d("log2=", error.toString());
        Log.e("log3=", error.toString());
    }
});
//excecute your request
queue.add(stringRequest);
```

See more here: [Learn volley](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/volley/index.html)

Comment: No problem, glad to've helped, I have added a link to some volley documentation in my answer. I recommend you take a look!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, urlString, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
            strr = response;
            pDialog.hide();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            pDialog.hide();
            Log.e("Volley", "ERROR");
        }
   });
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```